# I want fetch the documents in reverse order from collection in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to fetch the latest doc from the collection first in `mongoose`. I am using mongoose with `nodejs/expressjs`

Also, I am doing pagination on the server side so I can't reverse this after fetching.

```
exports.getProjects = (req, res, next) => {


const page = +req.query.page || 1; 
let totalItems;
Project
    .find()
    .countDocuments()
    .then(numProducts => {
        totalItems = numProducts;
        return Project.find()
            .skip((page - 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
            .limit(ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
    })
    .then(result => {
        return res.status(200).json({
            projects: result,
            currentPage: page,
            itemCount: totalItems,
            itemsPerPage: ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

};

Comment: try to post code content instead of screenshot.

Comment: Databases don't usually have a [user-facing] notion of "start/end of a collection/table". And I can't think of a dataabase that lets you control where the record physically goes in the data files. If you want specific ordering when reading data back, use an explicit `ORDER BY` or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You can include sort in your query . you did not mention any attribute eligible for sorting like date, or any number. you can use aggregation as below

```
const projectscursor = await Project.aggregate([
{$match:Query},
{$sort:{field:1}},
{$skip:number},
{$limit:somenumber}
])
```

Comment: First You need to select field like "createdAt" and then use mongoose .sort({createdAt:-1}) or aggregate with sort like in this example.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for `sort()` function in mongoose. You can simply sort your collection by using any of the following techniques.

```
Project.find({}).sort('test').exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Project.find({}).sort([['date', -1]]).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Project.find({}).sort({test: 1}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Project.find({}, null, {sort: {date: 1}}, function(err, docs) { ... });
```

Try one of the upper techniques according to your requirements with the following code for proper pagination.

```
app.get('/projects', async (req, res) => {
  // destructure page and limit and set default values
  const { page = 1, limit = 10 } = req.query;

  try {
    // execute query with page and limit values
    const projects = await Project.find()
      .sort({ field : criteria})
      .limit(limit * 1)
      .skip((page - 1) * limit)
      .exec();

    // get total documents in the Project collection 
    const count = await Project.countDocuments();

    // return response with posts, total pages, and current page
    res.json({
      projects,
      totalPages: Math.ceil(count / limit),
      currentPage: page
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

**Where**
criteria can be `"asc"`, `"desc"`, `"ascending"`, `"descending"`, `1`, or `-1`

Comment: Exactly I was looking for this